# Aligning single column layout

Tags: layout, legibility

In his article "[Designing Learn JavaScript’s course portal](https://zellwk.com/blog/learn-javascript-portal-design/)", Zell Liew chose [a single column layout aligned closer to the left](https://zellwk.com/blog/learn-javascript-portal-design/#layout).

He defends his choice by explaining that it improves legibility. Unfortunately, he doesn't cite any sources to corroborate his claims.

Where can I find more information on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning they provide is incredibly weak leading me to believe there is no basis for this decision other than personal preference. I don't see what difference having the content awkwardly off to the left of the screen rather than centered has on being able to find the next line. Both layouts use left-aligned text which is the thing that actually helps legibility.

Personally I find the non-centered layout worse as it requires the user to turn their head when shown on larger/wider displays. It is really jarring on an ultrawide display as it appears unbalanced and leaves half the screen completely blank.

Answer (score -1):

**Aligning a column to the left has to do with Accessibility.**

Left-aligned columns of text are easier to read for the users with disabilities like dyslexia as the uneven space between characters in the left and right-justified can be difficult to understand.

According to WCAG SC# [**1.4.8**](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-visual-presentation.html)

> People with certain cognitive disabilities have problems reading text
>   that is both left and right justified. The uneven spacing between
>   words in fully justified text can cause "rivers of white" space to run
>   down the page making reading difficult and in some cases impossible.
>   Text justification can also cause words to be spaced closely together,
>   so that it is difficult for them to locate word boundaries.